# SVD to transform regularization problem

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-optimization, svd, regularization

Can anyone explain this transformation to me :

$$
||Ax-b||_2^2 + \delta ||x||_2^2 : A \in R^{m,n}, b \in R^m \rightarrow \\
\tilde{x} = (V^Tx, V_2^Tx), \tilde{b} = (U^Tb, U_2^Tb)\\
V_2 \in R^{n x (n-r)}, \, V_2^TV_2 = I, \, V_2^TV = 0\\
U_2 \in R^{m x (m-r)}, \, U_2^TU_2 = I, \, U_2^TU = 0\\
\rightarrow ||Ax-b||_2^2 + \delta ||x||_2^2 = 
\sum_{i=1}^r(\sigma_i \tilde{x}_i - \tilde{b}_i)^2 + 
\sum_{i=r+1}^m \tilde{b}_i^2, \, ||x||_2^2 = \sum_1^n\tilde{x}^2
$$

I get that a singular value decomposition is used :

$$A = U \text{diag} (\sigma) V^T = \sum_{i=1}^r \sigma_i u_i v_i$$

But I have no idea about the rest of the transform. I'd like to know the intuition behind it, if someone can point to a reference or explain, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that for an  orthogonal matrix, we have $\|Ux\|^2=\|x\|^2$, since rotation and reflection doesn't change the length.

\begin{align}
\|Ax-b\|^2 + \delta \|x\|^2 &= \|U \Sigma V^Tx-b\|^2 + \delta \|x\|^2 \\
&=  \|U (\Sigma V^Tx-U^Tb)\|^2 + \delta \|V^Tx\|^2 \\
&= \|(\Sigma (V^Tx)-U^Tb)\|^2 + \delta \|(V^Tx)\|^2 \\
&= \|(\Sigma \tilde{x}-\tilde{b})\|^2 + \delta \|\tilde{x}\|^2 \\
&=\sum_{i=1}^r (\sigma_i\tilde{x}_i-\tilde{b}_i)^2+\sum_{i=r+1}^m \tilde{b}_i^2
 + \delta \|\tilde{x}\|^2\end{align}

Comment: Hi thanks so much, but where does $V_2$ and $U_2$ come in?? Also, where does the second summation from $r+1 \rightarrow m$ come from?

Comment: my $V$ is actually your $[V, V_2]$ and my $U$ is your $[U, U_2]$. The second summation is due to only the first largest $r$ singular values are positive, the rest of them are zero, rather than $\tilde{b}_i^2$, they are actually $(0 \cdot \tilde{x}_i-\tilde{b}_i)^2$.

Comment: Thanks, why would they break up $V$ into $[V, V_2]$ like that? Is there some utility in that? Also, you mean just in general case if those singular values from $r+1 \rightarrow m$ exist, then you organized them in their own term?

Comment: From the objective, only the first $r$ components of $\tilde{x}$ can take non-zero values.  In terms of solving and recovering the initial solution, only the first $r$ non-singular vectors are needed. Hence we can just compute an economical SVD rather than a full SVD.

Comment: Where did you study this? Some kind of advanced linear algebra course? You're like math king

Comment: $n$ years ago, where $n$ is huge, I took a class that is based on Gene Golub's matrix computation. I am not strong in maths, still learning everyday.